# Differential of composition of maps between vector spaces.

Tags: vector-spaces, differential, chain-rule

I am having some trouble to derivate : I know that if I consider a map between vector spaces, $f : V\to W$ then I will have for $x\in V$ :

\begin{align}
Df(x) &\in L(V,W)\\
(D(Df))(x) = D^2f(x) &\in L(V,L(V,W))\\
(D(D^2f))(x) = D^3f(x)&\in L(V,L(V,L(V,W)))
\end{align}
and so on...

But then I don't really understand how do derivate compositions. For example if I have $g,h : Z\to V$ and and we consider $y(t)=D^2f(g(t))(h(t))$ then how do we derive $Dy(t)$, where $t\in Z$?

Comment: What is $Df{}$?

Comment: it is the differential, i.e. $Df(x)$ is the mapping $L$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-L(h)\|_{W}}{\|h\|_{V}}=0$

Comment: Do you know the chain rule (from calculus)? It tells you how to differentiate a composition. $D(f \circ g)_x = Df_{g(x)} \circ Dg_x$.

Comment: @Nick, I saw this but I am unsure on how to apply it here.

Comment: @Nick, I think I kind of don't really understand what are $f$ and $g$ in this case

Comment: The question is still not very clear. What is $g$? (did you mean to say $g,h \colon Z \to V$ instead of $f,h$?) And what is $t$? Is it an element of $z$?

Comment: @Nick, yes exactly, I edited